# I want to apply noise to a volume that is depicted by a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, noise-generator

I have a greyscale volume that contains an object of interest. I can import it into python as a three dimensional numpy array with floats between -1 and 1.

My issues are twofold:

1. the negative floats shouldn't really exist however I am not sure how to replace each negative float with a random positive float. The methods I have used for array replacement in the past apply the same rule to all numbers below 0. Any help with this would be very much appreciated. I tried the following line but obviously it ends them all in being replaced by one random number:

   ```
   numpyarray[numpyarray < 0] = random.uniform(0,1)
   ```
2. I wish to apply noise across the whole image. I wish to do this in such a way I could apply the noise as many times as I want and everytime it will be random. I also wish to maintain the object, i.e stuff outside the object should become noisier than the object itself but both should become noisier than the original volume. The object tends to have the highest positive float numbers however that is not to say the occasional voxel in the noise could not have a value in the same range, but this is ok.

I have a function to make a random array of noise of the correct size (100x100x100):

```
def RandomNoise():
    NoiseArray = np.random.uniform(0,high=1,size=(100,100,100))

    return NoiseArray
```

And I can then just multiply my volume by this array however it doesn't do a good job at maintaining the object of interest.

I am wondering whether I could work out a curve and depending on where the intensity sits on the curve would define how the noise would be implemented but I am struggling to imagine how this would all work. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To replace negative values with random values, one simple way is:

```
numpyarray = np.where(numpyarray < 0, np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=numpyarray.shape), numpyarray)
```

However, that will generate many random values that will not be used. If you want to save that work, you can do:

```
m = numpyarray < 0
numpyarray[m] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=np.count_nonzero(m))
```

About the noise, you can scale it but a function depending on the intensity. For example

```
numpyarray_noise = np.clip(numpyarray + RandomNoise() * (1 - numpyarray), 0, 1)
```

Using `(1 - numpyarray)` will make the noise smaller the higher the intensity in the volume. You could also use `(1 - numpyarray) ** k` with some `k > 0`, or something exponential like `np.exp(1 - 1 / (1 - numpyarray + eps))`. You could also have some rule like "apply 10% of the noise and scale the other 90% according to the intesity".